# Splitting html elements into associated groups OR how to avoid blur event for specific elements

Tags: javascript, html

(This scenario is applicable to touch devices, but for the solution it doesn't really matter)

There is a page with a input element and a dropdown list. Depending on what user types, the dropdown element is populated.

**When user touches any of the elements on the page except of a dropdown list, the input element should loose the focus.**

To do so there is a global event watcher to blur an active element when user touches some other object on a page.
At the moment **I am looking for a generic way to specifying cases when the active element should not be blurred (touching the dropdown list should not blur the input)**.

My idea was to give some tags/attributes to the elements to identify that they are in the same 'family group' and that clicking on one of the children of the group while another is active should not trigger blur event.

However, as those elements can contain children and user clicks on the children, I need to tag every single element or go through the DOM hierarchy to find a parent, which is a dirty solution.

Any suggestions how this can be handled?

I am using Anguarjs.

Thanks a lot!